# eigenvalues of sparse matrix c++ Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigenvalue

I am using Eigen libraries to find the eigenvalues of my matrices in C++. This worked fine until I- somewhat by accident- noticed during simulation runs, that for about 10% of the runs (all of the runs are parametrized in the same way, only  a new seed is provided), Eigen does not find any eigenvalues for my matrices. The matrices are all 100x100 in size, and are filled with 1s and 0s (adjacency matrix). It works fine in the other runs, and since I pass my own seeds, I can indentify the problematic  runs. It seems that somehow the composition of the adjacency matrix in those  cases causes a problem. Also, if I increase the numbers of 1s in the matrix and reduce the number of 0s (by increasing the number of connections between individuals), I do not get this problem. Does anyone  have an idea, what could be causing this problem?

Thank you,
Niccola

Comment: Are you looking for the largest eigenvalue, the largest `n` or simply all of them? -- Do you by any chance know which algorithm is at play?

Comment: Eigen 3.2.4 states that the implementation is based on JAMA (Java Matrix package) which itself is based on EISPACK/LINPACK (Fortran based). So you can look into those to dig deeper. Also, you could try Arnoldi Iteration for sparse matrices.

Comment: I am looking for the largest eigenvalue, but at this point, it is not finding any at all. This is the code I am using:
`
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> es;
Eigen::MatrixXd /*adjacencyMatrix*/g
es.compute(g, /* computeEigenvectors = */ true);
es.eigenvalues();
std::cout<<"Eigenvalues are: " << es.eigenvalues()  << std::endl;`

Comment: You write in the title, that it's a sparse matrix, but at least in your previous comment, you're using a dense representation, and therefore algorithms. I have one suggestion: make sure that there are eigenvalues for the matrix. To me, it sounds like you have a row/column of zeros.

Comment: I guess that your problem is symmetric, therefore you might try the `SelfAdjointEigenSolver` class to take advantage of this. Can you come up with a smaller failing example so that we can have a closer look at it.